# How to know if timeout occurred in cypher query?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I'm using `apoc.cypher.runTimeboxed` https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.1/cypher-execution/cypher-timeboxed/

I'm using the HTTP API of neo4j. I'm making HTTP post requests like below.

[image: HTTP request on developer tools of my browser]

Here I do **NOT** see any difference if the results are really empty or if the results are empty because **TIMEOUT OCCURRED**. I think there should be a warning or error message.

Comment: @cybersam do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

An [APOC enhancement request](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures/issues/1233) was created for this in 2019.

And there were a couple of commits addressing this, but they have not been merged for some reason. You may want to add comments to that request.